# Create function jquery check input val

Tags: jquery

Create function check input.val

Could someone help?

**position check and add product**

```
    <p>Check all input val(not same) to Add product</p>
    <div id="product_table">
          <div><input type="text" class="p_id" name="p_id" value="d-001"></div>
          <div><input type="text" class="p_id" name="p_id" value="d-002"></div>
    </div>
```

**select list to click function**

```
    <p>Select Product(Form Database) to click function</p>
        <div id="prduct_list">
         <ul>
          <li onclick='fill_p("d-001");' value="d-001">d-001</li>
          <li onclick='fill_p("d-002");' value="d-002">d-002</li>
          <li onclick='fill_p("d-003");' value="d-003">d-003</li>
          <li onclick='fill_p("d-001");' value="d-004">d-004</li>
          <li onclick='fill_p("d-002");' value="d-005">d-005</li>
          <li onclick='fill_p("d-003");' value="d-006">d-006</li>
         </ul>
        </div>


//function check
    function fill_p(Value) {
        var html = '<div><input class="p_id" value="'+Value+'"></div>';
        var inputpid = $('#product_table').find('.p_id:input').val();
    if(inputpid !== Value){
          $('#product_table').append(html);
    }
    }
```

[enter image from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV5fJ.jpg)

Comment: Please write what you want to check?

Comment: Did not understand the problem you are facing. Do you want to read selected `li` value and create input if not already there and if already there then add value?

Comment: ul list >> by database, and function to check input val to add not same

Answer (score -1):

ul list >> by database, and function to check input val to add not same

[image: enter image from]